# Compare Date in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I building an ASP.NET application that connects to SQL Server 2008 R2. I having a brain fart on this one. I am trying to get some records between a date that the user chooses.

The application builds a sql statement and sends it to the server and waits for a return of records. The SQL statement looks like this.

```
SELECT * From policy pp where 20160115 between pp.policy_begin_date and pp.policy_end_date
```

It returns all records.

Do I need to convert '20160115' to a datetime variable? If so how do I convert that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Like this:

```
... WHERE CAST('2016-01-15' AS DATE) BETWEEN ...
```

Unless it's really a datetime.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
From policy pp 
where cast('20160115' as datetime) between pp.policy_begin_date and pp.policy_end_date
```

You can use [CAST or CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You SHOULD cast/convert your string to date, because it is depending on the language of the server if it works.

Best way is to use convert and give information about language:

```
convert(date[time], '20160115', 112)
```